# 2D(or even multi-dimensional) array storing and accessing handled by OS

Tags: arrays, data-structures

From what I have learned so far, 2D array is as well stored in as a linear 1D array in memory. Now my question is let's say I have declared a 2D array(5*5), initialized it and now I want to access the index (3, 4). I will simply write arr[3][4], but how actually is OS accessing the element. How will the OS get to know that from what index the 2nd row, the 3rd row and so on starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The OS has nothing to do with it. As far as the OS is concerned the process is accessing one of its own variables; the OS does not care what processes do with their own memory. (OK, the OS may get notified that a memory page needs to be allocated or retrieved from cache, but that's something quite different.)
2. You probably mean how does the *compiler* generate code to access the array element.

   - Let's say that we speak about a program in the C language, and the declaration was

     `long arr[5][5];`
   - The compiler will then compile

     `arr[i][j]`

     into `* (* (arr + i) + j)`, which, in machine code, resolves to

     `LOAD` address `arr` into a register

     `ADD` *i* times the size of a row (in our case, `i` times 5 times `sizeof(long)`)

     `ADD` *j* times the size of an element

     Now the register holds the address of `arr[i][j]`.
3. For the question as asked, how does the compiler address `arr[3][4]`, the answer is that all this computation is done at compile time (because the indices are constants), and the access is as efficient as the access to any simple variable.
4. Multi-dimensional arrays are not only *stored* as single dimensional arrays. They really *are* single dimensional arrays, at least in languages such as C. Your example `arr[5][5]` is an array with 5 elements (the first `5` in the declaration). Each *element* of the array is an array of 5 elements (the second `5` in the declaration).